# Is SUB value of OAuth2.0 ID token constant

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, apple-oauth2

Currently I'm developing "SignIn via Google/Apple" functionality for my app.

On some stage of interaction between my app and Google/Apple I will obtain an ID token. The possible payload of the token is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types) for Google and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) for Apple. In both cases it contains `SUB` property. Google describes it like

> the ID that represents the principal making the request

I have several questions

- Does it mean that `SUB` value is linked one-to-one with the particular user and will not change tomorrow, after one month or whenever I will ask Google/Apple for this token again?
- Can I consider `SUB` value as a `external_user_id` in my app?
- Is it possible for Google/Apple user to obtain this SUB value in Account settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub claim is unique for a given user and should never change. The format of the sub, can however vary between services, sometimes it is a string, sometimes it is a guid. So just treat it as a string.

Calling the received sub claim in the ID-token external_user_id in your database is totally fine.

The user does not care about the sub value and usually it is internal and not visible on the user account/profile page.

Comment: be aware that when you're dealing with more than one provider, you'll have to make the user id unique by appending a Provider specific postfix/prefix to the "sub" claim value, since the sub namespace may be overlapping between Providers